# SQL Server SELECT to timely return the most recent record

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

I have the below ‘PriceData’ database table that contains roughly 1,000,000 rows and is growing by about 100,000 records/day:

```
Id   | DateCreated    |TradeDate        |fk_Currency | Price
--------------------------------------------------------------
48982| YYYYMMDDhhmmss | YYYYMMDDhhmmss  |1           | 1.09684
48953| YYYYMMDDhhmmss | YYYYMMDDhhmmss  |1           | 1.22333
48954| YYYYMMDDhhmmss | YYYYMMDDhhmmss  |2           | 1.22333
```

My requirements mandate I must be able to retrieve the most recent price for a given currency input, the below stored procedure achieves this but takes far too long to execute (3.4 seconds):

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRecentPrice] @currency nvarchar(6)
SELECT Price from PriceData 
WHERE Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM PriceData 
    WHERE fk_CurrencyPair = (SELECT Id FROM CurrencyPair WHERE Name = @currency));
```

SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 78 ms,  elapsed time = 3428 ms.

I’ve tried including the below where clause that only examines the past minute of data:

```
AND TradeDate >= (SELECT (DATEADD(MINUTE, -1,  (SELECT CONVERT(datetime, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time'))))
```

But it’s only brought the execution time down by about 700 milliseconds:

CPU time = 62 ms,  elapsed time = 2762 ms.

I’ve also considered creating a new table that only stores the most recent price for each currency and is simply updated whenever a new price comes into the PriceData table.  However that feels like a dirty hack and I’m sure violates some database normalization principles.

This stored procedure is executed by a web service layer which is consumed by an MVC application so the execution time needs to be much better (I'd like to get it to < 100 milliseconds).  I’m open to modifying the architecture of this table and database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `TOP 1` with a `JOIN` and see how it compares to your original query:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRecentPrice] @currency nvarchar(6)
SELECT TOP 1 t1.Price
FROM PriceData AS t1
JOIN CurrencyPair AS t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
WHERE t2.Name = @currency
ORDER BY t1.Id DESC
```

You should also place an index on `Id` field of both `PriceData` and `CurrencyPair` tables.

Comment: Thank you.  In regards to the Indexes; SQL Server has by default included clustered indexes on the respective primary keys.  Are these indexes sufficient for my use case?

Comment: @slashNburn yup, if you have created the primary key on id field then the clustered index already created on that field. but, if you set the sort order to `DESC` then you don't need to use the order by clause, just put the id field in select statement.

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos:  Thank you very much for the help with this, very elegant answer.  SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 2 ms

Answer (score 0):

Have you try something like this?

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRecentPrice] @currency nvarchar(6)
SELECT TOP 1 p.Price from PriceData p 
JOIN CurrencyPair c ON p.fk_CurrencyPair = c.Id
WHERE c.Name = @currency
ORDER BY p.Id DESC;
```